# Appending/editing to a text file by creating it first from values from HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a few values which are coming from a json via socket call through the hardware on my html page,now these values are getting changed continously over duration of 3 secs.
I want to create a text file which can append the values (not replace them) to these continuously changing values.
What i've done is called a function on change event which creates a new text file every time a change event is trrigered.What i want it is to create a single file and append values inside it,whats happening now is its creating a new file every time value changes.
My code is as:

```
saveTextAsFile:function(d)
{
    console.log("data sent is",d);
    var textToWrite = d;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "testdata.txt";
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null)
    {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
},

 destroyClickedElement: function(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable textFileAsBlob is a Blob object, it cannot be changed.

> A Blob object represents a file-like object of immutable, raw data.
>   [Blob - Web API Interfaces | Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

Therefore you should do all of your concatenation work in Javascript before the file is created, or you should do work on the file on the server side.

Comment: that does not fulfil my purpose.My page is getting crashed after a few minutes of inactivity.It shows the "Aw snap" error and i have to reload the page again.I'm trying to note the counter after which the browser is crashing so i'm, trying to write that counter in a text file,so when the browser crashes(we have to reload the page when it crashes so the counter sets to 0 then) ,we can know the counter after how much time it crashed.Is there a better solution to my problem than what i'm trying to do?

Comment: Depending on how big the data you are trying to save (seems like just a counter so possibly small), you might want to try saving to Local Storage.  console.log is usually the best for debugging... writing to a file to debug will be time consuming and might not give you all info you need.  Try saving to a local storage object that generates a unique datetime based key when the app runs